# Intellij Modules are forgotten on rebuild

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

I have added all the jar modules I need for my project in a folder called 'libs'. I right click 'Add as library' and the module is implemented and will work for the duration of that build.

My problem is that whenever I rebuild the project in anyway it 'forgets' about these modules and I have to re add them over and over.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am using gradle**

Comment: Would you consider using maven and configuring `<dependencies>`.

Comment: That should work. Which IDEA version? How do you "rebuild"?

@vikingsteve: Even if manually attaching jar files as libs is not the way to go for a "real" project. For some quick throwaway stuff it is fine, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Any IDEA version from about 12 up (current version 15 is superb) should handle maven projects correctly.

Make yourself a `pom.xml` and put at the root of your project.

The `<dependencies>` section defines your libraries (they must have their own pom.xml).

IntelliJ will automatically sync the libraries in your project whenever you make changes to the pom.xml. Thus you avoid having to add or remove modules manually any more.

You can either run your java code as normally, or run a maven goal such as `install` from the maven pane on the top right.

Hope this helps! Once you start using maven (or an equivalent tool like gradle) your life with multiple dependencies will get much easier.